# Design pattern for animation sequence in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

What design pattern to use for sequence of animation that involve different actor in libGDX. For example I am making a game to choose a wolf from a group of sheeps. The first animation played when the game begin is the wolf enter the field that is filled with two sheeps.Then the wolf disguise as a sheep and goes to the center of the screen. Then the game will shuffle the sheeps. After it finished it will ask the player where is the wolf. The game wait for player input. After that the game will show animation to show the player whether their answer is right or wrong.

I am currently using State design pattern. There are four states wolfEnterState,DisguiseState,ShuffleState,UserInputState, and answerAnimationState. I feel that my code is messy. I use addAction with action sequence and action completion(new Runnable()) a lot. I feel that the action sequence is getting long. Is there a better solution for this kind of problem

Answer (score 1):

One option is to give the Wolf class a disguise function.
This could look something like this.

```
class Wolf {
    void disguise(Animation p_target) {
        this.animation = p_target;
    }

    void animate() {
        play(this.animation);
    }

    void reveal() {
        play(this.animation.reveal);
    }
}
```

Another option is to create a child DisguisedWolf class.

```
class Wolf {
    void animate() {
        play(this.wolf_animation);
    }

    void reveal() {
        play(this.wolf_reveal);
    }
}

class DisguisedWolf extends Wolf {
    void animate() {
        play(this.sheep_animation);
    }
}
```

I believe it would be beneficial to present the same interface no matter what the state is. 
This makes it easier to iterate over a collection and call the animate function.

```
sheep.move(center);
sheep.shuffle();

wolves.move(center);
wolves.disguise(as_sheep);
wolves.shuffled();


creatures.shuffle();

promptPlayer();
// Now you can blindly call reveal
creatures[player.clicked_creature].reveal();
```

Or try this..

```
creatures = wolves + sheep;
creatures.move(center);
creatures.disguise();
creatures.shuffle();
promptPlayer();
// Now you can blindly call reveal
creatures[player.clicked_creature].reveal();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of having one class for wolves and sheep that has a `boolean isWolf;` and when it is clicked it calls `animate()` that is something like this:

```
public void animate(){
    if (isWolf) {
        //play wolf animation
    } else{ 
        //play sheep animation 
    }
}
```